# xlPlacement Enumeration with pasted objects in VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, variable-assignment, copy-paste, naming

I'm writing a macro that copies charts from `xSheet1` and pastes them into `xSheet2` as pictures. I'd like to give the pictures the xlMoveAndSize property, but I can't find a good way to do it.

I've tried to do something like this:

```
For Each xPic In xSheet2.Pictures
    xPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
Next
```

The only problem with this method is that my `xSheet2` contains thousands of pictures and it takes ages to go through all of them. It's redundant to reset the `xlMoveandSize` property on all of them except the 8 most recently pasted pictures, so if I could somehow reference only those pictures or assign them to picture objects when I paste them into the sheet, I could significantly reduce the time it takes to run the current design.

When the pictures are pasted into `xSheet2` they are not necessarily assigned the names "Picture 1" through "Picture 8" (or "Picture n-8" through "Picture n"), so I don't believe I can call the pictures by name unless I can set what their name will be prior to pasting them. If I could 'paste' the pictures directly into a variable, that would be ideal, though I think there may be a fundamental issue with that idea.

The only other work-around I can think of would be to export the charts from `xSheet1` as pictures and save them in a temporary cache on the users hard drive with something like: `xChart1.Export Filename:="C:\CachePath\Chart1", Filtername:="PNG"` and import them into `xSheet2` with something like `xPic1=xlApp.xSheet2.Pictures.Insert("C:\CachePath\Chart1")`. I'd really like to avoid this if possible though.

This is how I'm currently moving the pictures:

```
Sub GetChartPics()

'Variables
    Dim xSheet1 as Worksheet        'source
    Dim xSheet2 as Worksheet        'destination
    Dim xChart1 as ChartObject      'chart1 from source
    Dim xChart2 as ChartObject      'chart2 from source
    '...
    Dim xChart8 as ChartObject      'chart8 from source
    Dim xPic as Picture

'Set chart objects and worksheets
    'I'll spare the details here. I don's see how they'd be relevant, anyway.

'Move Charts
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    xChart1.Chart.CopyPicture
    xSheet2.Paste Destination:=xSheet2.Range("A3")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    xChart2.Chart.CopyPicture
    xSheet2.Paste Destination:=xSheet2.Range("B3")

    '...

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    xChart8.Chart.CopyPicture
    xSheet2.Paste Destination:=xSheet2.Range("H3")

'AssignMoveAndSize Property to pics
    For Each xPic in xSheet2.Pictures
        xPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next
```

Thanks

Comment: `xSheet2.Shapes(xSheet2.Shapes.Count)` will typically return the last-added shape, so you could set the placement after each paste operation

Comment: @TimWilliams I think that would work, however many of my shapes have been assigned the same index, for example there are many `"Picture 7"`s  (not sure how this happened, honestly). I can't find much information about how indexing is assigned online, but it seems that something is reseting the index back to 0 intermittently. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: There's no link between the index and the name.  For example, if you delete "Picture 1" through "Picture 6" and "Picture 7" was the only one remaining, it would have an index in the shapes collection of 1.  Typically a pasted picture will have a distinct name, but you can't rely on that being true.

Comment: @TimWilliams That explains the issues I'm having. Thank you. Unfortunately, I'd like to be able to delete pictures if needed. Unless I search through the entire shape array (which is what i was trying to avoid in the first place) I can't think of a good way to find the empty indices.

Comment: If you give the picture a unique name immediately after pasting it then you can always refer directly to it.

Comment: @TimWilliams I think that would still require me to know which index the picture is being pasted into. I've discovered that for some reason the macro runs much faster if instead of `For Each xPic in XSheet2.Pictures` I use `For Each xShape in xSheet2.Shapes`. This has the same effect, but still takes a bit of time, so to I just display a modeless userform that says "please wait..." while the macro runs in the background. This solution works acceptably well for my purpose. Thanks for your help!

Comment: A pasted picture is always pasted such that it's the last index at the time of pasting - as noted above, if you immediately *name* it with a known name you can then refer to it directly at any point later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that the macro runs much faster if instead of `For Each xPic in XSheet2.Pictures` I use `For Each xShape in xSheet2.Shapes`. This has the same effect and, although faster, still takes a bit of time. To make the macro a bit more aesthetic, I just display a modeless userform that says "please wait..." while the macro runs in the background. This solution works acceptably well for my purpose.

This is an abbriviation of what the code looks like now:

```
Sub GetChartPics()

'Variables
    Dim xSheet1 as Worksheet        'source
    Dim xSheet2 as Worksheet        'destination
    Dim xChart1 as ChartObject      'chart1 from source
    Dim xChart2 as ChartObject      'chart2 from source
    '...
    Dim xChart8 as ChartObject      'chart8 from source
    Dim xShp as Shape

'Show modeless userform
    Load PleaseWait
    PleaseWait.Show (0)

'Set chart objects and worksheets
    'I'll spare the details here. I don's see how they'd be relevant, anyway.

'Move Charts
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    xChart1.Chart.CopyPicture
    xSheet2.Paste Destination:=xSheet2.Range("A3")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    xChart2.Chart.CopyPicture
    xSheet2.Paste Destination:=xSheet2.Range("B3")

    '...

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    xChart8.Chart.CopyPicture
    xSheet2.Paste Destination:=xSheet2.Range("H3")

'Assign MoveAndSize Property to Shapes
    For Each xShp in xSheet2.Shapes
        xShp.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next

'Close Userframe
    Unload PleaseWait
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the shape may have nothing to do with the index of the shape in the `Shapes` collection.

This is what I'm suggesting you use:

```
xChart8.Chart.CopyPicture
xSheet2.Paste Destination:=xSheet2.Range("H3")

With xSheet2
    .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Placement = xlMoveAndSize
End With
```

I've never seen a pasted shape *not* be the last index position on the worksheet.